# How can I check and display the word between two other specific words?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

The user will enter a string value that will contain two “bread” word. My program will printout the string that is between the first and last appearance of "bread" in the given string, or print “There is no sandwich!” if there are not two pieces of bread. For example, for the input "breadlolbread", the output should be "lol".

```
String a = "There is no sandwich!";

for (int i =0;i<len-3;i++) {
    if ((s.charAt(i)== 'b')&&(s.charAt(i+1)== 'r')&&(s.charAt(i+2)== 'e')&&(s.charAt(i+3)== 'a')&&(s.charAt(i+4)== 'd')) {

    }   
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my anseer and if it suits your need, accept it. @coder123

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something slightly different. For example, for the input "breadlolbread", the output should be "lol". Therefore, I only take a 1 word input possibly consisting of a "sandwich"(displays the word between the words "bread").

Comment: Well, that code would apply for that scenario as well : breadlolbread would output lol. @coder123 Just try it with String text="breadlolbread"; and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "There are two bread which are very cool bread.";
        String bread = "bread";
        //make a new string by taking everything from first index of bread string+length of a bread string word and the last index of bread.
        String inBEtween = text.substring(text.indexOf(bread)+bread.length(), text.lastIndexOf(bread));
        //if the length inbetween trimmed of leading and tailing whitespace is greater than 0, print inBetween, otherwise print "No sandwich".
        if (inBEtween.trim().length() > 0) {
            System.out.println(inBEtween);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No sandwich.");
        }
    }
```

Of course, you could do this with regex too

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "There are two bread bread.";
        String pattern = "(?<=bread)(.*)(?=bread)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No sandwich");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two various ways. First one is to create a regular expression that will match the whole sentence i.e. two words provided by the user with the word between them.

The other way is probably easier, You can use `split()` method to split String into the separate words and then simply iterate over the whole array to find the words you are looking for. The example would be :

```
String userWord = "bread";
String word = "There are bread various bread breeds of dogs";
String[] wordSplit = word.split("");
for(int i = 0; i < wordSplit.length-2; i++) {
    if(wordSplit[i].equals(userWord) && wordSplit[i+2].equals(userWord)) {
        System.out.println(wordSplit[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you just forgot this but the String#split() method requires an argument. And you do not compare strings for equality with `==`. Use the String#equals() method instead. Also ensure that `[i+2]` won't take you out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, of course! I wrote the code here and simply forgot that. Fixing that now. Thanks! As for the `i+2` the condition in the for loop ensures that we end the iteration at the index equal to `wordSplit.length - 3`